# How to convert an array of JSON to BLOB type in node.js

Tags: node.js, blob

I have an array containing JSON which I have to insert into cassandra database table having column of data type blob.
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html
Above link says --  For example, bigintAsBlob(3) is 0x0000000000000003 and blobAsBigint(0x0000000000000003) is 3.
But I cant make it to work for my scenario.
I am using helenus driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert JSON to a string, and save it as a BLOB using `textAsBlob(content)` function in Cassandra.

To load, just read that blob to a string using `blobAsText(content)`, and then decode it as JSON.

---

To clarify things out, BLOB is Binary Large Object. But you can also alter the Schema to use *varchar* or *text* datatype instead of BLOB.

Comment: Thanks @alandarev -- I am getting ReferenceError: textAsBlob is not defined.

Comment: @anand Happy to help. I must have mentioned that it is a function in Cassandra, not JavaScript itself.  P.S. Do not forget to upvote me if you found my answer useful.

Comment: I will upvote @alandarev -- unfortunately I am not eligible for upvoting at the moment.

Comment: the question is javascript not cassandra.

Comment: @loekTheDreamer the question mentions  `I have to insert into cassandra database`, thus I see nothing wrong in the provided answer that uses the tools user is working with.